# Angular & Xrm WebApi: Cannot assign result to class variable

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamics-crm, xrm

I'm building a base Angular 8.2 webressource for Dynamics CRM, but I can't manage to assign a value to a class property.

The code is the following :

HTML

```
<div>
  Hello {{loggedInUserName}} from {{ title }}.<br/>
  <br/>
  The first retrieved user from WebApi was {{ firstUserFullName }}
</div>
```

and the controller :

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'XRM-Angular-Base-App';
  loggedInUserName: String;
  firstUserFullName: String;

  ngOnInit() {
    let context = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext();
    this.loggedInUserName = context.userSettings.userName;
    console.log("Logged in user: " + this.loggedInUserName)
    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("systemuser", "?$select=firstname,fullname&$filter=firstname eq 'Alexandre'").then(
      function success(result) {
        alert(result.entities[0].fullname);
        this.firstUserFullName = result.entities[0].fullname;
        alert(this.firstUserFullName);
      },
      function (error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.message);
      }
    );

  }
}
```

When debugging (with the .map files), code goes to the first alert ( `alert(result.entities[0].fullname);` ), show the correct result ("Alexandre Someone"), but don't do anything on the next instruction (`this.firstUserFullName = result.entities[0].fullname;`), and the second alert is never shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to access `this` so you have to use `arrow operation (=>)` in `success callback` and in `error callback` like below

```
Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("systemuser", "?$select=firstname,fullname&$filter=firstname eq 'Alexandre'").then(
  result => {
    alert(result.entities[0].fullname);
    this.firstUserFullName = result.entities[0].fullname;
    alert(this.firstUserFullName);
  },
  error => {
    alert("Error: " + error.message);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, the second alert now shows the correct text. In another hand, the HTML still don't update. Do you know why ?

Comment: Not sure. You can try detect change

Comment: The JS variable shows the right value, but HTML don't. I'll ask a new question about this, thank you for your time.

Comment: No need please try detect change for angular

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-change-detection-in-angular